# How to make query perform better using a dependent sub query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query from two large tables of data. I am trying to join them but filter out the minimum date at the same time, the filtering date seems that it slows it down ALOT. But this is a must have, Is there any way I can speed it up? As the query stands, it just keeps loading and loading

Here is what I'm getting in the EXPLAIN

[image]

The query is -

```
SELECT T1.id_no, 
       T1.condition_code, 
       Count(T1.condition_code) AS COUNT, 
       T1.doe, 
       T2.id_no, 
       T2.trans_time, 
       T2.from_routing_pos 
FROM   attrcoll_month T1 
       JOIN live_trans T2 
         ON T1.id_no = T2.id_no 
WHERE  T2.trans_time = (SELECT Min(trans_time) 
                        FROM   live_trans T2_MIN 
                        WHERE  T2_MIN.id_no = T2.id_no) 
       AND T1.doe BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-02 23:59:59' 
       AND T1.unique_code = 'XXY' 
GROUP  BY T2.from_routing_pos, 
          T1.condition_code
```

Snippets from each tables data -

**ATTRCOLL_MONTH T1**

```
ID_NO   DOE                CONDITION_CODE   UNQIUE_CODE
8442    25/09/2014 22:49    NEND             XXY
8442    25/09/2014 22:49    SEND             XXY
8442    25/09/2014 22:49    BS               XXY
8442    25/09/2014 22:49    BS               XXY
8442    25/09/2014 22:49    BS               XXY
8442    25/09/2014 22:49    TD               XXY
8511    25/09/2014 22:49    NEND             XXY
8511    25/09/2014 22:49    SEND             XXY
8511    25/09/2014 22:49    BS               XXY
8511    25/09/2014 22:49    BS               XXY
8511    25/09/2014 22:49    BS               XXY
8511    25/09/2014 22:49    TD               XXY
8511    24/09/2014 12:49    OF               XXY
8511    24/09/2014 12:49    OF               XXY
8675    24/09/2014 12:49    NEND             XXY
8675    24/09/2014 12:49    SEND             XXY
9081    24/09/2014 12:49    NEND             XXY
```

**LIVE_TRANS T2**

```
ID_NO   TRANS_TIME  UNQIUE_CODE FROM_ROUTING_POS
8442    2.12276E+17 XXY          OD1
8442    2.12276E+17 XXY          OD2
8445    2.12276E+17 XXY          OD3
8214    2.12276E+17 XXY          OD2
8325    2.12276E+17 XXY          OD1
842     2.12276E+17 XXY          OD3
2444    2.12276E+17 XXY          OD3
```

Sorry about the table data formatting!

Hope this is explained well, please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First fetch record from t1 only into a temp table.
2. Then Apply the join of temp Table and T2 and t2_min and get all min time and ids
3. Then merge #1,#2 and t2 in join and apply group by. 
   This will give some some boost in performance.

Basic Idea is to limit the records that will be part of Join and to remove the subquery.

This is sample:-

```
--Fetch records from Table one based on all filtering conditions
        -- this will reduce the logical read when we apply join
        SELECT
            T1.id_no,
            T1.condition_code,
            T1.doe
        INTO
            #Temp
        FROM
            attrcoll_month T1
        WHERE
            T1.doe >= '01/09/2014'
            AND T1.doe < '03/01/2014'
            AND T1.unique_code = 'XXY';

        -- Get all the min time for only required ids. This will avoid the sub query and also read get reduced since records in #temp are
    limited
        SELECT
            MIN(trans_time) MinTime,
            T.id_no
        INTO
            #tempMinTime
        FROM
            #Temp T
            JOIN live_trans T2_MIN ON T.id_no = T2_MIN.id_no;
        --Merging #1 and #2
        SELECT
            T1.id_no,
            T1.condition_code,
            COUNT(T1.condition_code) AS count,
            T1.doe,
            T2.id_no,
            T2.trans_time,
            T2.from_routing_pos
        FROM
            #Temp T1
            JOIN #tempMinTime T ON T1.id_no = T.id_no
            JOIN live_trans T2 ON T.id_no = T2.id_no
        WHERE
            T2.trans_time = T.MinTime
        GROUP BY
            T2.from_routing_pos,
            T1.condition_code;
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I'm pretty new to sql, how would I do it your way could you show code??

Comment: sure I will provide soon

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the following error ?   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
            attrcoll_month T1
        WHERE
            T1.doe >= '2014-' at line 7

Comment: oh ok Use the between statement that you have instead of that.
Those syntax are from SQL Server. This is just sample for you . Please correct where ever needed.

Comment: It's not the between, it's saying the FROM statement is wrong?

Comment: As I mentioned dear please change the syntax accordingly

like 
For #1
Create a temporary table and then insert records in that.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I understand now, will have a go at it, sounds pretty logical, hopefully it should work, I will post back if I get it working, thanks man!

Comment: you are welcome.
I got a good boost in my proc by following this:)

Comment: followed your idea and it now takes 1 second to run! huge performance increase, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a correlated subquery which means that for every record in the main table (t1), it is running the query within t2.  You may want to swap it around by having a sub-query just get all IDs and the minimum date first, THEN join back to the t1 table for the rest of the details.

```
select
      FT1.id_no, 
      FT1.condition_code, 
      Count(*) AS ConditionCount, 
      FT1.doe, 
      FT2.id_no, 
      FT2.trans_time, 
      FT2.from_routing_pos
   from
      ( select
              t1.id_no,
              min( t2.trans_time ) as MinTime
           from
              attrcoll_month t1
                 JOIN live_trans T2 
                    on t1.id_no = t2.id_no
           where
                  T1.doe BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-02 23:59:59' 
              AND T1.unique_code = 'XXY' 
           group by
              t1.id_no ) as PreQuery
      JOIN attrcoll_month FT1
         on PreQuery.ID_No = FT1.ID_No
      JOIN live_trans FT2 
         ON PreQuery.id_no = FT2.id_no 
        AND PreQuery.MinTime = FT2.trans_time
   group by
      FT2.from_routing_pos, 
      FT1.condition_code
```

To help query, I would have the following indexes on the tables

```
attrcoll_month index = (unique_code, doe, id_no )
attrcoll_month additional index for secondary join = ( id_no, condition_code )

live_trans index = ( id_no, trans_time )
```

This way, the "PreQuery" is only getting the IDs that qualify the date/time and get the min date ONCE.  Then, since you have the IDs, just re-join to get the rest of the details.

Comment: @Engl12 Alter table before query.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the min() or max() tuple can be expressed in terms of `NOT EXISTS( lower / higher)` :

```
SELECT T1.id_no 
       , T1.condition_code
       , Count(T1.condition_code) AS COUNT 
       , T1.doe 
       , T2.id_no 
       , T2.trans_time 
       , T2.from_routing_pos
FROM   attrcoll_month T1 
  JOIN live_trans T2      
    ON T1.id_no = T2.id_no      
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM   live_trans T2_MIN               
          WHERE  T2_MIN.id_no = T2.id_no
            AND T2_MIN.trans_time < T2.trans_time
          )    
       AND T1.doe BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-02 23:59:59' 
       AND T1.unique_code = 'XXY' 
GROUP  BY T2.from_routing_pos, T1.condition_code
        ;
```

Comment: tried this but it didn't seem to make a difference, thanks though!

Comment: In both cases, an index on {id_no, trans_time} will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the row number in the result of:

```
SELECT T2.*
  FROM attrcoll_month T1 
  JOIN live_trans T2 ON (T1.id_no = T2.id_no)
 WHERE T1.doe BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-02 23:59:59' 
   AND T1.unique_code = 'XXY'
```

If the query above result a few rows, select it into a temp table first. If It does not affect much,  maybe you should redesign your tables.

Some code maybe a little better:**(Updated)**

```
SELECT T1.id_no, 
       T1.condition_code, 
       Count(T1.condition_code) AS COUNT, 
       T1.doe, 
       T2.id_no, 
       T2.trans_time, 
       T2.from_routing_pos 
FROM   attrcoll_month T1 
JOIN   (SELECT live_trans.id_no, min(live_trans.trans_time) min_trans_time
          FROM live_trans
          JOIN attrcoll_month ON (live_trans.id_no  = live_trans.id_no)
         WHERE attrcoll_month.doe BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-02 23:59:59' 
           AND attrcoll_month.unique_code = 'XXY' 
         GROUP BY live_trans.id_no) T2_MIN ON (T1.id_no = T2_MIN.id_no)
JOIN live_trans T2 
         ON (T2.id_no = T2_MIN.id_no AND T2.trans_time = T2_MIN.min_trans_time)
WHERE  T1.doe BETWEEN '2014-09-01 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-02 23:59:59' 
  AND T1.unique_code = 'XXY' 
GROUP  BY T2.from_routing_pos, 
          T1.condition_code
```

If the first query return much fewer rows, using the Temp Table instead of the huge T2. In other hand, if (t2.id_no, t2.trans_time) has duplicate record, the result maybe not correct, because the condition of t2 join t2_min may create multiple rows. To confirm it, try this Query

```
SELECT t2.id_no, t2.trans_time, count(*) AS my_count
  FROM (
       SELECT t.id_no, min(t.trans_time) as min_trans_time
         FROM live_trans t
        GROUP BY t.id_no) t1
  JOIN live_trans t2 ON (t2.trans_time = t1.min_trans_time)
HAVING my_count > 1
```

If the query return rows, Use NOT EXIST statement in other answer, replace T2 with the first query in my answer as subquery.

Comment: tried both of the queries but both still won't run, they just keep loading and loading :(